# min-height with calc function not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap panel [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/h3e1uk54/) where myself trying to set the `min-height` of `panel-body` class as,

```
.panel-body {
      min-height: calc(100% - 100px);
    }
```

Why it is not working in the given fiddle? Is `calc` function browser dependent?

Comment: height 100% of what?

Comment: [Check this](https://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/)

Comment: @Paran0a height 100% of body height

Comment: @Paran0a See my answer as to why height: 100% doesn't mean what you think it means.  It means 100% of its direct parent. If the direct parent has not got any height specified, the child can't be 100% of its parent, as its parent get its height determined by the child content.

Comment: Sorry that last comment shouldn't have been directed at you @Paran0a but at mpsbhat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.container` doesn't have any height set so it will be as tall as its child element, who are trying to be 100% of its height.  See the dilema?
Make `.container` have 100% height (And all its parents too) and you should see some success?

See my fork of your fiddle: [Fixed Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h959mpfp/2/)

Comment: @mpsbhat I assume you mean the fiddle isn't working, rather than the method I described? That was just because of a wrong link - I've fixed the link now...

Answer (score 9):

check [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/)

you can check css-trick's post about sticky-footer, it sets sticky footer in 5 different ways

```css
.content {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 70px);
}
.footer {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="content">
    content
  </div>
  <footer class="footer">sticky footer</footer>
</body>
```